# Using raw_input to define what variable list to search

Tags: python, raw-input

How can i use the raw_input value stored in rowChoice be used in count? i.e. right now i define A.count. How would i wtite the correct equivanlent of rowChoice.count, where the user defines which of A,B,C,D to seach through.

```
A = ['available', 'unavailable','available','available','available']
B = ['unavailable', 'unavailable','available','available','available']
C = ['available', 'unavailable','unavailable','available','available']
D = ['available', 'unavailable','available','unavailable','unavailable']

rowChoice = raw_input('What row would you like to sit in? >> ')

count = A.count('available')
print'there are %r seats available in this row' %(count)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be best to use a dictionary for this:

```
d = {'A': ['available', 'unavailable','available','available','available'],
     'B': ['unavailable', 'unavailable','available','available','available'],
     'C': ['available', 'unavailable','unavailable','available','available'],
     'D': ['available', 'unavailable','available','unavailable','unavailable']}

letter = raw_input().upper()    
d[letter].count('available')
```

Comment: @user2212774 Each list is mapped to a letter. eg. `'A'` so `d['A']` will return that list and you you use `.count` like before. http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries. `.upper()` makes sure it also works if I try `d['a']`

Comment: it would be cleaner if writted `d = { 'A': [ 'available', 'unavailable ... ], 'B': [ ... ], ... }`

Comment: @XavierCombelle Ok true, I don't know why I thought it would look good this way haha

Comment: could you explain why it is best to use a dictionary?? also, why does the line **d[raw_input().upper()].count('available')** start with **d[....** what is happening here?? i understand the rest. thanks

Comment: @user2212774 A dictionary is the most simple way to do this, also it is the fastest because you can access any key instantly. `d[k]` access the dictionary at key `'k'`, you are going to have to read the python dictionary link I sent you since they explain it better than I can

Comment: @user2212774 I split the code up a bit, I hope that makes it easy to understand

Comment: is there a way to print the index of each 'available' item in a specific list? i.e, so after being able to say, there are 3 seats available in row B, i can then print another statement that says what index theese available seats are at?

Comment: `[i for i, item in enumerate(d[letter]) if item == 'available']`

Comment: I completely understand this, apart from I often see loops like this start with something like **i for i**. I don't understand why it is written like this??

Comment: Look up list comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

If you dont wanna use dictionary, You can use this function "ord"

```
ord('A')  #65 
ord('a')  #97  , then use
i = ord('A') - 65 # use i as index to your created list = [A,B,C,D]
created_list = [A,B,C,D]  #then
i = ord(rowchoice) - 65
count = created_list[i].count('available')
```